# Azure REST API App with authentication for easy access from Mobile app (Xamarin.forms)

Tags: rest, azure, xamarin.forms, azure-mobile-services, azure-api-apps

I would like to develop a REST API app that I can access from both web app and mobile app.

The REST API need to support simple authentication that can be done in both from a web app and from a mobile app (like Xamarin.forms)

I don't need multiple users, I need simple access control to my API.

I tried to develop a Azure API app with AD authentication, but it seem like it is very difficult to add support to Azure API App.

**To summarized my questions:**

1. How to do simple authentication in Azure API App or Mobile App?
2. Should I use API App or Mobile App or something else?
3. Does it support Xamarin and Web app access?

Answer (score 1):

This is way too broad.  Are you doing data access?  Do you need simple auth?  Have you tried any of the quickstarts to try to learn about your task?

1. Look at Azure App Service Authentication / Authorization - it provides a server directed flow for web and mobile access
2. This should have been your first question.  You want an ASP.NET app, running on App Service (I'm biased here).  It should cover both API, Mobile and Web together.
3. Yes, the App Service covers all your needs.

Comment: yes I'm doing data access, I have looked at quickstarts that I could find, didn't find anything useful... I have a working API App with AD Auth, but it difficult to add access using xamarin.forms.